# Fast Fourier Transform algorithm wrong by a single minus sign

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

So after watching this video on the fast fourier transform https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7apO7q16V0

I analysed the pseudocode and implemented it in python to find out that it was producing a different output to that of many fft calculator sites. My values seem to be all there its just odd, as the order is out of place, anyone know why. Is it a different kind of algorithm implementation or something.

```py
import cmath
import math
def FFT(P):
    n= len(P)

    if n == 1:
        return P

    omega = cmath.exp((2 * cmath.pi * 1j)/n)

    p_even = P[::2]
    p_odd = P[1::2]

    y_even = FFT(p_even)
    y_odd = FFT(p_odd)

    y = [0] * n

    
    for i in range(n//2):
        y[i] = y_even[i] + omega**i*y_odd[i]
        y[i+n//2] = y_even[i] - omega**i*y_odd[i]
    return y

    
poly = [0,1,2,3]
print(FFT([0,1,2,3]))
```

The site I tested it against was https://tonysader.github.io/FFT_Calculator/?
and I input into this site 0,1,2,3 and obtained: 6, -2+2J, -2, -2+-2J

whilst my python program output : 6, -2-2J, -2, -2+2J

The pseudocode I followed:

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t follow YouTube videos to learn these things. There’s no quality control on these, people can say whatever they want in these videos! This one seems to be missing a minus sign. Compare to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley–Tukey_FFT_algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the program you're running is executing the inverse FFT.  Try
`omega = cmath.exp((-2 * cmath.pi * 1j)/n)`.  Note the minus sign.

Comment: Oh right so i changed my omega to match that and its correct now. So my question now is, whats the difference. I assume all implementations use euler part as going anticlockwise then, would my result be wrong fast fourier transform then?

Comment: It's part of the magic of the FFT.  The FFT and its inverse operation are almost identical operations except for a change of sign.  If you apply the inverse FFT to the result of the FFT, you'll get your original values (module floating point error) back.

Comment: And as you probably figured out, which operation is the "FFT" and which is the "inverse FFT" was an arbitrary decision, probably made by Gauss or Fourier.

Comment: wait, so you are saying the inverse fft is what I did,  or that they are arbitrary. It cannot be as numpy.ifft(0,1,2,3) is not the values mine gave. From what you have said just the imaginary part has changed , which represents the phase shift and so is not too important right?

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood what I meant.  There is a single FFT operation.  Everyone agrees what the meaning of the FFT operation is, and it always involves the negative sign.  However as you've discovered, the operation and its inverse are nearly identical.  If 200 years ago, Fourier had swapped the two operations, math would have continued just fine.  But he didn't and we don't.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeahhh, I get that. Do you know what the complex part actually means though , I have seen the word phase shift used but not sure what they are meaning precisely in this context.

Comment: Maybe check this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&t=950s.  And I told you a slight lie.  There is also a factor of 1/N that's in the inverse FFT that's not in the FFT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238632/discussion-between-simon-balfe-and-frank-yellin).